# Scraping from from Autoscout24.it with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Greetings form Italy, I'm a beginner in Python and I need some help with a project that I want to create.

I want to scrape all the data with Python from the following website: https://www.autoscout24.it/lst?sort=standard&desc=0&ustate=N%2CU&cy=I&atype=C (the link is actually the full database that I want to scrape, that are more than 350k cars)

I have found a guide here in this german website https://statisquo.de/2020/01/16/autoscout24-mining-webscraping-mit-python/ but I'm not able to let work the code in my computer, can somebody help me?

My aim is to create a csv file with all the info's of the car like: year, price, model_name, car_producer_name... etc etc...

(here you are the code took from the german website)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer #HTML parsing
import urllib.request #aufrufen von URLs
from time import sleep #damit legen wir den Scraper schlafen
import json #lesen und schreiben von JSON-Dateien
from datetime import datetime #um den Daten Timestamps zu geben
import re #regular expressions
import os #Dateipfade erstellen und lesen
import pandas as pd #Datenanalyse und -manipulation

folders = ["data/visited/","data/autos/"]

for folder in folders:
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        os.mkdir(folder)
        print(path, "erstellt.")
    else:
        print(folder,"existiert bereits")

path_to_visited_urls = "data/visited/visited_urls.json"

if not os.path.isfile(path_to_visited_urls):
    with open(path_to_visited_urls,"w") as file:
        json.dump([],file)

countries = {"Deutschland": "D",
             "Oesterreich": "A",
             "Belgien" : "B",
             "Spanien": "E",
             "Frankreich": "F",
             "Italien": "I",
             "Luxemburg": "L",
             "Niederlande": "NL"}

#countries = {"Deutschland": "D"}

car_counter=1
cycle_counter=0

while True:

    with open(path_to_visited_urls) as file:
        visited_urls = json.load(file)

    if len(visited_urls) > 100000:
        visited_urls = []

    multiple_cars_dict = {}

    cycle_counter+=1

    for country in countries:

        car_URLs = []

        for page in range(1,21):

            try:
                url = 'https://www.autoscout24.de/lst/?sort=age&desc=1&ustate=N%2CU&size=20&page='+str(page)+ '&cy=' + countries[country] +'&atype=C&'
                only_a_tags = SoupStrainer("a")
                soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(),'lxml', parse_only=only_a_tags)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Übersicht: " + str(e) +" "*50, end="\r")
                pass

            for link in soup.find_all("a"):
                if r"/angebote/" in str(link.get("href")):
                    car_URLs.append(link.get("href"))

            car_URLs_unique = [car for car in list(set(car_URLs)) if car not in visited_urls]

            print(f'Lauf {cycle_counter} | {country} | Seite {page} | {len(car_URLs_unique)} neue URLs', end="\r")
        print("")
        if len(car_URLs_unique)>0:

            for URL in car_URLs_unique:
                print(f'Lauf {cycle_counter} | {country} | Auto {car_counter}'+' '*50, end="\r")
                try:
                    car_counter+=1

                    car_dict = {}
                    car_dict["country"] = country
                    car_dict["date"] = str(datetime.now())                    
                    car = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.autoscout24.de'+URL).read(),'lxml')

                    for key, value in zip(car.find_all("dt"),car.find_all("dd")):
                        car_dict[key.text.replace("\n","")] = value.text.replace("\n","")

                    car_dict["haendler"] = car.find("div",attrs={"class":"cldt-vendor-contact-box",
                                                                 "data-vendor-type":"dealer"}) != None

                    car_dict["privat"] = car.find("div",attrs={"class":"cldt-vendor-contact-box",
                                                               "data-vendor-type":"privateseller"}) != None

                    car_dict["ort"] = car.find("div",attrs={"class":"sc-grid-col-12",
                                                            "data-item-name":"vendor-contact-city"}).text

                    car_dict["price"] =  "".join(re.findall(r'[0-9]+',car.find("div",attrs={"class":"cldt-price"}).text))

                    ausstattung = []

                    for i in car.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"cldt-equipment-block sc-grid-col-3 sc-grid-col-m-4 sc-grid-col-s-12 sc-pull-left"}):
                        for span in i.find_all("span"):
                            ausstattung.append(i.text)

                    ausstattung2 = []

                    for element in list(set(ausstattung)):
                        austattung_liste = element.split("\n")
                        ausstattung2.extend(austattung_liste)

                    car_dict["ausstattung_liste"] = sorted(list(set(ausstattung2)))

                    multiple_cars_dict[URL] = car_dict
                    visited_urls.append(URL)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Detailseite: " + str(e) + " "*50)
                    pass
            print("")

        else:
            print("\U0001F634")
            sleep(60)

    if len(multiple_cars_dict)>0:
        df = pd.DataFrame(multiple_cars_dict).T
        df.to_csv("data/autos/"+re.sub("[.,:,-, ]","_",str(datetime.now()))+".csv",sep=";",index_label="url")
    else:
        print("Keine Daten")
    with open("data/visited/visited_urls.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(visited_urls, file)
```

Comment: What's your error message / response?